# Break then continue the loop

Tags: php

I need to break the loop if the title is empty Then continue the loop array

Something like this

```
for($i=0;$i<count($out[0]);$i++){

$title = "$z->extract('<title>','</title>',$data);"

   if (empty($title)) {
       break; // Don't continue the sentences below and continuw the next value from the loop
   }
//more sentences php
//more sentences php
//more sentences php
//more sentences php
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($out[0]);$i++){

$title = "$z->extract('<title>','</title>',$data);"

if (empty($title)) continue;
 //more sentences php
 //more sentences php 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you use `continue;` instead of `break;` to resume to the next loop without processing the further lines.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
continue;
```

instead of break;

Answer (score 0):

You need to just replace `break` with `continue`

Answer (score 0):

You have two choises:

```
if (empty($title)) {
      $i++;
}
```

or

```
if(!empty($title)){
//more sentences php
//more sentences php
//more sentences php
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Explanations: consider the loops are**

```
while {
   foreach {
     if($i == 2) {
       continue 1; //means going to foreach and continue the loop
       continue 2; //means going to while and continue the loop
     }
   }
}
```